# Windows sets TV to wrong resolution

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, tv

I'm running a 3080ti on my PC which has three devices hooked to it: 1 HDMI 4K (4096x2160) Samsung *TV* plugged via a Soundbar, 1 DisplayPort Ultrawide Monitor, and 1 Rift S over DisplayPort. This setup worked just fine until I fancied trying Windows 11 (with a fresh install, no upgrade), from there on whenever I turn on my TV it works as usual but as soon as I turn off my Monitor Windows tries to set the TV to 720x480i resolution for whatever reason. The TV doesn't like this so it either shows a black screen or a "Mode Not Supported" error.

I thought it might be a growing pain of Windows 11 so I re-installed a fresh copy of W10 but the problem persists. I don't think it's a hardware problem because this used to work flawlessly before I foolishly tried W11.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIiTq.jpg DXDiag and Driver screenshots

This is annoying because my TV is on another room so leaving my monitor on is just wasting energy and the lifespan of the monitor.

Is there anything I can do to "force" Windows to use 4096x2160 on the TV at all times? It may also be trying to fall-back to the "recommended" resolution which the TV doesn't like either.

Comment: only thing I can suggest is, have you tried connecting directly to the TV rather than through the soundbar ... or power cycle the soundbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to directly hook the PC to the TV without the soundbar between them and things are back to working-order. I am still puzzled by why it used to work flawlessly in the past.